# insert back slash before every quote in Visual Basic VBA Strings

Tags: vba, excel

As the title says it, I would like to insert back slash before every quote in Visual Basic VBA Strings. Thanks.

Here's what I tried to do right now (it doesn't even compile):

```
 Dim n As Integer
    n = UBound(value) - LBound(value) + 1
    Dim parsedValue As String
    parsedValue = value
    For i = 1 To n
        If parsedValue.Chars(i) = "'" Then
            n = n + 1
            parsedValue = Left(parsedValue, i) + "\'" + Right(parsedValue, n - i)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What is `value`? What do you mean by `before every quote in Visual Basic VBA Strings`?

Comment: If you're thinking of using this to escape SQL, don't.  Use parameters instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example to insert `backslash` before every quote in a string without looping through the entire string.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sString As String

    sString = "This is a sample string has 'quotes' in it"

    Debug.Print sString
    'This is a sample string has 'quotes' in it

    sString = Replace(sString, "'", "\'")

    Debug.Print sString
    'This is a sample string has \'quotes\' in it
End Sub
```